# Ubuntu top-bar broke during ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, 20.10

so i was upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10 with success then i rebooted my pc 2 times to make sure the update worked and then this happenes:
[The top menu bar broke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Iq66.png)

it isn't showing the calendar and the power menu anymore.
does anyone know how to solve this?

thanks for the support.

Comment: the menu bar shows the icons back after opening and closing my laptop but i dont want to do that every time and then it is still buggy anyways.

Comment: You've either themed it, or have a gnome-shell extension that doesn't work in 20.10. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable them, restart gnome-shell or log out/in. The re-enable one at a time, restarting gnome-shell each time, and see if the problem returns.

Comment: i disabled all extensions but that didnt work

Comment: i reenabled them but it made no difference

Comment: OH!!!!!! It worked again! i dont know why and how but it worked again!

Comment: Did you restart gnome-shell after each disable? Only re-enable ONE extension at a time and retest.

Comment: no i didnt do that; i restarted after disabling all extensions and that did nothing.

Comment: then i reenabled them all and that didnt work neither

Comment: and then suddenly it fixed it's self!